# How to set Spotify as default Music Player?

Tags: music-player, music, default-applications

I want spotify to appear in the drop-down menu instead of the default music player. Is this possible?

(I stream all of my music, so I don't need the default music player).

(By "drop down menu", I mean the one you drag down from the top of the screen -- the place where you can see everything that's going on. Is there a name for that "place"?)

Comment: Drop down menu = notification bar/area. Also, what phone do you have? My Galaxy S only shows the default music player there when i'm using it, and does the same with spotify.

Comment: Same problem with my CyanogenModed Desire HD. I'd like to specify a default media player to be used through A2DP (with blue tooth)