# How to Make Spotify the Default Music Player in CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, music, music-player, default-applications, spotify

I cannot find any setting for the feature in Settings. 
I want Spotify takes over the buttons' actions in the lock screen. So drawing the next symbol should play Spotify's song instead. I do not want to remove the built-in one (Eleven).

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: Cyanogenmod 13
Related: [How to set Spotify as default Music Player?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12169/9897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want it "default"? Play music when clicked file in a file manager, or take over media button actions?

Maybe simply disable/remove the built-in one (Eleven)? Do note that Eleven is capable of playing music directly from file managers, and Spotify may not have this function.

Comment: Take over the button actions. So drawing the next symbol should play Spotify's song instead. - I do not want to remove the built-in one.

Comment: @Masi Try using apps like MyAndroidTools to disable Eleven's MediaButtonIntentReceiver. That will at least stop Eleven from responding to media buttons.

Comment: I tested MyAndroidTools. It only works with root access, but I do not want to enable it.

Comment: @Masi Enable root, do the tweaks in MyAndroidTools and disable root. The changes should theoretically persist even if MyAndroidTools is gone.